# JSON not deserializing some values

Tags: c#, json

I’ve got a base class (which is used a base for a `User` class):

```
public abstract class UserB2C
{
…
    public List<SignInName> SignInNames { get; set; }
…
}

public class SignInName
{
    string Type { get; set; }

    string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And some JSON which includes:

```
\"signInNames\":[{\"type\":\"emailAddress\",\"value\":\"user@yahoo.co.uk\"}],
```

which is passed to:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);
```

But the object created (deserialised) has:

```
    "signInNames": [
        {}
    ],
```

Any ideas why the field doesn’t get populated?
There is no error generated.
All other (simple) values get populated ok.

I've tried changing the case of `Type` and `Value` to match the JSON string,
and also tried explicitly creating the `List<SignInName>` when the object is created, but to no avail.

Comment: How are you deserializing? What is in the list? Why is the class abstract?

Comment: @radders post your deserialize code.

Comment: @radders and also a complete JSON object.

Comment: You're going to be closed if you don't show exactly how you're serializing/deserializing. You might want to show this.

Comment: OP edited to show further info...

Comment: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json) here you use User class instead of UserB2C

Comment: Have you considered renaming Type to something else in the C# code and adding an annotation to serialize that as "type"?

Comment: @radders can you please edit with complete json string  and user class structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Properties of `SignInName` class should be declared as `public` in order to be deserialized with values.

```
public class SignInName
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json = 
        "{\"signInNames\":[{\"type\":\"emailAddress\",\"value\":\"user@example.com\"}]}";
        var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);
        System.Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user)); 
    }
}

public abstract class UserB2C
{
    public List<SignInName> SignInNames { get; set; }
}

public class User : UserB2C {  }

public class SignInName
{
    string Type { get; set; }
    string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Output is `{"SignInNames":[{}]}`

If we make `SignInName` class properies `public` the output will be:

```
{"SignInNames":[{"Type":"emailAddress","Value":"user@example.com"}]}
```

Comment: They don't have to be, object should still deserialize. What his problem will later be is that he won't be able to access those properties but let's assume he knows that as this is not part of his current issue.

Comment: It will deserialize but with null values.

Comment: Edit: I misread the question, I just noticed he is showing an item in the List.. my bad :)